# How to get an IType from a class name in Eclipse JDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm implementing a variant of the JUnit New Test Suite Wizard, and instead of getting test classes from the current project, I need to get them from another source.  They come to me as strings of fully-qualified class names.

Some of them may not yet exist in this user's workspace, let alone in the classpath of the current project.  The user will need to import the projects for these later, but I don't want to mess with that in my wizard yet.  I need to just add all classes to the new suite whether they exist yet or not.

For those classes that are already in this project's classpath, I can use IJavaProject.findType(String fullyQualifiedName) .  Is there an analogous way to get ITypes for classes that are not (yet) visible?

I would be happy to construct an IType out of thin air, but ITypes don't seem to like being constructed.

Comment: (It's funny that voting up someone's answer to my own question is not something a new user like me can do.)

Comment: For the moment I'm playing with the idea of implementing a HypotheticalType object that implements IType.  I'm hoping that the existing wizard code will actually need only a handful of the methods of the IType and related interfaces, just barely enough to treat these as glorified Strings containing the names of the yet-to-be-imported classes.

Comment: An alternative, of course, is to majorly retrofit the existing wizard code to use Strings instead.  However, that feels like a second-class solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible: the Java Document Model interfaces are created based on the classpath.

Even worse, if the project do not exist in the users workspace, the resulting code would not compile, and that is another reason for not allowing the arbitrary creation of such constructs.

If I were you, I would try to help the user to import the non-existing projects in case of types are not available, thus avoiding the tackling with the Java Document Model.

Comment: That the resulting code would not at first compile is acceptable in this case.  The same thing would happen if the user pasted the desired classname strings into their new JUnitTestSuite before importing the projects.  And I also look forward to triggering some kind of import in a future iteration of this wizard.  When I do that, I'm hoping I can find a straight-forward way to populate the project import wizard with the projects required.  But that's a different topic than my original question.

Answer (score 1):

For my purposes, creating a `HypotheticalType` and a `HypotheticalMethod` got the job done.  I'm attaching an overview in case anyone else needs to follow this path.

First I created a `HypotheticalType` and had it implement the `IType` interface.  I instantiated one of these at the proper spot in my modified wizard.  Using Eclipse's Outline view I created a method breakpoint on all methods in my new class.  This let me detect which methods were actually getting called during execution of my wizard.  I also modified the constructor to take, as a `String`, the name of the class I needed the wizard to handle.

Almost all of the new methods are ignored in this exercise.  I found that I could keep the default implementation (return null or return false in most cases) for all methods except the following:

- the constructor
- `exists()` - no modification needed
- `getAncestor(int)` - no modification needed, but it might be useful to return the package of my hypothetical class, e.g. if my class is `java.lang.Object.class`, return `java.lang`.
- `getDeclaringType()` - no modification needed
- `getElementName()` - modified to return the class name, e.g. if my class is `java.lang.Object.class`, return `Object`.
- `getElementType()` - modified to return `IJavaElement.TYPE`
- `getFlags()` - not modified yet, but might be
- `getMethod(String, String[])` - modified to return a new `HypotheticalMethod(name)`
- `getMethods()` - modified to return new `IMethod[] { new HypotheticalMethod("dudMethod") }`

In the process I discovered that I need to be able to return a `HypotheticalMethod`, so I created that type as well, inheriting from `IMethod`, and used the same techniques to determine which methods had to be implemented.  These are the only methods that get called while this wizard runs:

- The constructor - add a `String` parameter to bring in the name of the method
- `exists()` - no modification needed
- `isMainMethod()` - no modification needed

That covers the solution to my original question.  Zoltán, I'll be doing as you suggested in an upcoming iteration and trying to assist the user in both the case in which the desired class is not yet in this project's classpath, and the case in which the desired class is in some project not yet in the workspace.